# Is it possible to run the kstream application to start from the particular offset in the kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

i am working in kafka streams application in springboot,here we are reading messages from 0th offset only till now,

so now i have  an usecase that if i need to consume from the 10000th offset or after any particular timestamp how can we do this in kstreams application?

in normal consumer we can use seek method to consume from particular offset but how can we do the same in kstreams application?

can anyone overcome this situation?

it would be helpful if you share you thoughts on this......

Comment: You can seek streams groups as well, but need to use the standard consumer api methods

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for the response, it would be very helpful if i get  any example or repo link to perform this functionality.(To perform seeking in kafka streams )

Comment: It's the exact same code as a normal consumer, nothing specific to streams other than knowing the correct group id

Comment: Thanks again @OneCricketeer i will try the same and will get back to you

Comment: Sure. Depending on the topology, you probably also want to clean up intermediate topics and state stores, too